# MVC Bootstrap accordion - determine with JavaScript if open or closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

If we have a collapsible panel initially defined like this

```
 <div id="ContactDetails" class="panel-collapse collapse">
```

How can I test to see if it is open or closed via JavaScript?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you need to ask yourself what the difference in css property or css class is when expanded vs collapsed.  You can easily then check that condition with JavaScript.  Inspect the elements in your browser and find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the class list in that element (in your case div id = "ContactDetails").

```
var classList = document.getElementById('ContactDetails').className.split(/\s+/);
for (var i = 0; i < classList.length; i++) {
   if (classList[i] === 'collapse') {
     //do something
   }
}
```

You can then browse through your classList[] if one of it is equal to "collapse".

Pure Javascript way:

```
var classList =$('#ContactDetails').attr('class').split(/\s+/);
$.each( classList, function(index, item){
    if (item === 'collapse') {
       //do something
    }
});
```

Comment: For some reason I couldn't get the second script to work, but the first one has done the job. Thanks for the fast response :-)

Answer (score 1):

With [JQuery.hasClass](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/):

```
$( "#ContactDetails" ).hasClass( "panel-collapse" )
```

Comment: One of the first things I tried was to look for .className in JavaScript and it returned positive regardless of whether the accordion was open or closed

Answer (score 1):

@Jocksan was close, except that the panel will always have the "panel-collapse" class (as @gchq found).  When it is opened the "in" class is added, and when it is closed the "in" class is removed.  So this will return true for open, false for closed:

```
$( "#ContactDetails" ).hasClass( "in" )
```

Here is more about the classes and how it all works: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion